# databse values not displaying in list view

Tags: php, android, android-listview

I'm working on an app that will receive data from database and get into `ListView` but the data is no displaying with an empty page, I am using where condition in `PHP`  file to receive plug number details only that will display on `ListView`.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -> add your code, show the error and where it occurs etc

Comment: paste your code here. Did you get the data from the server properly?